# Forecasting Future Revenue Data For ROI Calculation

Tags: time-series

I have some daily revenue data and I am trying to calculate the return on investment (ROI) by predicting what the expected revenue 'should be' and comparing it to what the company actually made. I used a moving average time series method on the data, but this assumes a linear trend, which is yielding poor results when calculating ROI because of the volatility in the actual data itself. I can post my results/data in an excel file if you want.

ROI is calculated using this formula: [(Actual Revenue - Forecasted Revenue From Time Series/Forecast Method) - Cost] / Cost Actual Revenue figures are given on a daily basis as is the cost.

I need to use an improved time series (or alternative) method to find an expected value for the several days worth of revenue. I am not sure what method to use as I am only familiar with the moving average time series method.

Can you please suggest a suitable method? Furthermore, if you have an example of how it works in excel, I would be grateful.

I have been told Stochastic Modeling is a good alternative as it is used to model stock prices but I cannot find a model in excel which I can use.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524510%28v=vs.93%29.aspx

In the 4th table down (entitled Solver Foundation Ribbon) in the link above, 
if you take a look at 'Method' in the 'Simulation' group it reads 'Sets options to solve stochastic models. Choose between Automatic (the default), Monte Carlo, and Latin Hypercube.'

I used Monte Carlo simulation to simulate a hypothetical stock price in my dissertation, alhough I didn't use Excel.  I used Maple.  I don't know what sort of stock you're dealing with.  Excel might not need to know that when employing the built in simulation methods it has for stochastic models.  You could try the default or built in Monte Carlo.  If that doesn't improve your results, you might want to write your own simulation. You may be able to do this in Excel itself. If you do want to try and write your own method, you might want to think about which sort of model would best fit the stock you're dealing with.  The example I dealt with was modelling energy prices (gas and electricity). Models used for those (which may or may not also apply to the stock you're dealing with) are Mean Reverting Processes (such as the Vasicek Model or the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model) and Jump Diffusion Processes (I think the latter are supposed to be more realistic).

I'd go for a jump diffusion model if you're tryng your own, but since I used mean reversion I'll just show you the method, which isn't too difficult:

the Vasicek model is $dS = a(b-S)dt + \sigma dz$

where

S is the spot price (or in your case revenue at a given time t)

dS is the expected change in price at a given time step

a is the 'mean reversion rate' (which you choose yourself)

b is the mean reversion level or long run equilibrium price (which again, you choose)

$\sigma$ is the volatility

dz is the random shock to price at a given time step

The idea is to solve this stochastic differential equation numerically (using Euler's method if you want to keep things reasonably simple or another method if you need to improve your results (i.e. Milstein method))

so the code I used (in Maple) was this:

(comments are actually done with a hash in Maple, but hash emboldens and enlarges in latex so I've changed hash to //)

// method stochEulerMRP takes the parameters you've chosen (start, a, b, $\sigma$, finalT, h) and uses Euler's method to produce and graph a prediction of how the stock price will change over the time you've specified

stochEulerMRP:=proc(start, a, b, $\sigma$, finalT, h)

(start = revenue or price at time $0$, a,b, $\sigma$ as above, h = time step, finalT = time you want simulation to run until)

global N, x;

local t, xLine, eps, i, pEuler, pLine, A B, Z;

N = floor(finalT/h);
t:=array([],0..N);
x:=array([],0..N);
eps:=array([],0..N);
xLine:=array([],0..N);

Z:=Random Variable(Normal(0,1)):
eps:=Sample(Z,N):

t[0]:=0;
x[0]:=start;
xLine:=0;

for i from 1 to N do
  t[i[]:=t[i-1]+h;
  x[i]:=x[i-1]+a*(b-x[i-1])*h+$\sigma$*eps[i]*sqrt{h};
xLine[i]:=xLine[i-1]+a*h;
od:

// plot results
pEuler:=[seq(t[i],x[i]], i=0..N)];
pLine:=[seq([t[i],xLine[i]],i=0..N)];
A:=listplot(pEuler,color=red, style=line, view=[0..1,-2..2]):
display(A);

end:

So that code produces one simulation (or guess) at how the stock price or revenue will change over the given time by using Euler's method to solve the stochastic differential equation you've specified using the Vasicek Model and choosing your own guesses of what the parameters a and b are.  Monte Carlo simulation relies on the fact you can produce more than one of these simulations and then take the average of all of them at each point you want to predict and the more simulations you do, the closer this average will be to the true mean (so it's used for solving stochastic differential equations where you don't already know the true mean because you can't find it analytically, as you can for the Vasicek Model). I used the Vasicek model to see how well my simulation process was working, by looking at how close my averages were to the true mean.

You have to choose b and $\sigma$ so that $\frac{2b}{\sigma^2}\ge1$ if you want to prevent the revenue going negative (which you only want to do if this is impossible).

You can find the true mean and variance of the Vasicek Model on the Wikipedia page.

I must say, I did have some problems with my models: the accuracy wasn't improving as it said it should have done in a book I was referring to on the subject, called something like The Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations (Kloeden and Platen), (the problem was that accuracy is meant to improve by a certain order each time you halve the time step, but mine wasn't improving by the amount theirs was in the book, even though I was using exactly the same equation and almost everything else exactly the same so there might have been a glitch or 2 in my implementation (possibly in the random number generation), but hopefully this will help to get you started, even if it doesn't immediately produce good enough results.

An example of values of a, b, and $\sigma$, finalT, and step size(h) I used are 0.05, 70, 0.2, 1, and 0.01 respectively, but obviously these depend on what you're modelling.

One problem with this is time: I was doing $1,000-1,000,000$ runs. $1,000,000$ runs was taking an hour or more, but you may not need to do so many, and you're pc may be faster than the one I was using at the time. $100,000$ runs might not have taken too long, and $10,000$ was fine.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and informative post. The problem I have is all I've got it daily revenue data, say Jan 1st - Dec 31st. I know the company spends, say, 1 million in June 1st on advertising. So, I need to use Jan 1st - May 31st data to predict what the rev should be without the 1m spend, and then I also know what it actually is because of the 1m spend (the 'actual' revenue). The issue is I cannot make assumptions as I know nothing more than the revenue figures. Whats the best method I can use please?

Comment: In all honesty, despite my dissertation, I'm no expert on the subject: just a beginner, but as I understand it, modelling always involves assumptions.  The modelling process works by taking a guess at the way you think things are working and comparing to your results and then trying to improve your model.  Of course you can make your model fit one set of data. The real test is to see how it performs on new sets of data.

Comment: I'd start by trying the default Excel stochastic model and see how it performs

Comment: And then if that's not good, maybe try the built in Monte Carlo.

Comment: Do you know of templates that I could use ie. paste my data in and see what the output is?

Comment: If those aren't working I'd try writing a jump diffusion model myself. You'd have to google jump diffusion models and just pick a relatively simple one to begin with and code it up using Euler's method.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. (apart from the one I put above, but it's a very short program. You could translate it into java or C# quite quickly.)

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't any, but it something I've not looked into.

Comment: or you could download Maple and use what I've put above as a template

Comment: I do see what you're saying about not making assumptions though. That's the part of the process I don't understand either, but apparently these models are used. I don't know if they look at past data to get some idea of the mean: I expect so. But the good thing about jump diffusion models (so I've heard) is that they're better at modelling volatile data (because they have random jumps). you do still have randomness in the MRPs, but no jumps.

Comment: You could try researching by googling 'how to predict stock prices with jump diffusion models'

Comment: It might get a bit hairy though: that's getting into research level stuff (some of it)

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help than that (which I realise might have been $0$ help). The only other thing to say is to quote this webpage www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/MathematicalFinance/Lessons/BlackScholes/Limitations/limitations.xml 'Mathematical models in finance do not have the same experimental basis and long experience as do mathematical models in physical sciences. For the time being, we should cautiously use mathematical models in finance as general indicators that point to the values of derivatives, but do not predict with high precision.' The author does go on to say

Comment: that math models are still used in finance

Comment: I personally think modelling revenue and stock prices is impossible: Modelling an aeroplane's systems works in general (although there are certain things that result in the plane having to crash land even if you know about them in advance like a flock of geese flying into the engine), but people and financial events are too unpredictable.

Comment: unless perhaps you're a good friend of God, but that's not maths

Comment: Yup whats expected to happen is just what needs to be modelled rather then what 'actually' happens as there are naturally some variations due to unforeseen circumstances. I'll have a look at the above though.

Comment: It says this on the webpage I put a link to above (the link didn't work just now, but it's the 5th one down of you google 'how to predict stock prices with jump diffusion models'): 'From a scientific point of view, the way to estimate the parameters is statistically evaluate the outcomes from the past to determine the parameters. We looked at one
case of this when we described historical volatility as a way to determine σ for the lognormal distribution, see Implied Volatility..'

Comment: It also says: 'Financial economists and mathematicians have suggested a number of alternatives to the Black-Scholes model. These alternatives include: stochastic volatility models where the future volatility of a security price is uncertain,
jump-diffusion   models  where   the   security   price   experiences occasional jumps rather than continuous change...In spite of these flaws, the Black-Scholes model does an adequate job of
generally predicting market prices.'

Comment: 'Generally, the empirical research is supportive of the Black-Scholes model. Observed differences have been small (but real!) compared to transaction costs.' So maybe try using the Black Scholes model, in which case the equation you'd be solving numerically would be $dS = rSdt + σS\epsilon \sqrt{dt}$ (where $\epsilon$ is a randon drawing from a standardised normal distribution, $\phi$ (0,1)$ instead of the Vasicek model

Comment: r is the risk free interest rate in this example, which might not apply to your example, but you could still try the same equation. r would just be some parameter you'd estimate based on the 1st 6 months' data.  S is the stock price (revenue in your case) at time t.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure what you'd do about r. It's $\sigma$ that the website suggests estimating from past data

Comment: This website looks like it could be useful: http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/mc/SalesForecast.html  you can download an Excel or Excel-like package (or at least example of) and it has info on what's going on. It mentions Profit = Income - Expenses and Excel as well as 'The Method: Use a Monte Carlo Simulation to estimate profit and evaluate risk.'

Comment: The above seems quite a good intro to how to use Excel to do Monte Carlo simulation.  The toughest bit is probably working out how your scenario compares to the one in the example and changing the model accordingly.

Comment: Interesting excel sheet. The issue is all I have is daily revenue data and I know what it is in the future period but need to use some model (doesn't need to be time series) to predict what it should have been without the 'shock' (i.e. the increased advertising budget). The only inputs are the daily revenue and the cost of the advertising. I'm not sure what model is good for this.... the ones you mention above seem rather complicated/based on a lot more assumptions which I do not have knowledge of. :( Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Also I can't have a model which changes i.e. based on RAND() as my team will freak out (they are non-mathematicians lol). Ideally it just needs to be a realistic line graph of some sort that reflects what 'should' have happened vs what did actually happen (we know what did actually happen).

Comment: I'm afraid I've spent way too long on the computer over the last few days, so I'm goinf to have to desert

Comment: I've found the strength to say this though: this may reveal considerable ignorance on my part, but wouldn't you just add the advertising budget back on?

Comment: to get what would've happened if the advertising budget hadn't increased (i mean add the increase in advertising budget back on of course)

Comment: What about linear regression?

Comment: I like @GeorgeTomlinson suggestion about linear regression. If you know anything about machine learning and using R you could code something up to get Ret. On Investment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Variable and Fixed cost analysis as an input to a forecast of future sales and costs.  I have a full blog about it linked below with an excel template.  I'll talk about your specific example as much as I can.

[Variable and Fixed Costs - Small Business Decisions](https://smallbusinessdecisions.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/variable-and-fixed-costs/)

Variable costs may change drastically from day to day, but the real point of what you're trying to do is understand the general trend so that you can forecast your expected ROI. You should use a longer period of time to understand what portion of your sales revenue is variable with the cost than a single day.  In the end, a month over month value for expected ROI should be sufficient. Daily analysis would be overkill in any of the business programs I've been involved in, most of which were multi-million dollar programs.

You should use the template provided to determine your variable costs.  The template is set up for 12 months if you have the data.  Then you should estimate what kind of sales volume you can expect to continue from your latest sales data.  The Sales team at your company should be able to help you with that.  With an understanding of the variable costs, you can project your expected sales and the expected costs associated with those sales.

If your company has several other products, I'd also suggest you use the sales revenue specific to your product as the top line instead of the overall company sales. This will help identify which portion of the overall company sales are correlated with your specific product. The two numbers should be relatively similar in percentage, but drastically different in scale. Ex: 12% variable cost for $1 Million in sales at the company level is $120,000.  14% variable cost of $10,000 in sales of your specific product is $1,400. Similar variable cost percentage rates, but vastly different scales.  Now, this comparison is important because in the case that another product had sales increases at the same time as your product, it'll be very difficult to ensure that the costs your allocating to your product are actually a result of your product's changes in sales.

If you work in a company that is so large your product won't make up the difference in a rounding error on their P&L (not an insult, I've been there), then you should look for standard allocations for SAR and add them to your direct costs.